# How do I change the change the timezone associated with a connection in MySQLConnector/Net?

Tags: c#, mysql, mysql-connector

I'm trying to insert a time into a MySQL table from a Unix timestamp which is already in UTC. Using `from_unixtime(timestamp)` works for parsing, but the timezone it uses is "the current time zone", which is apparently the current time zone for the *connection*, not the mysql server itself.

Is there a way I can change the time zone for the connection? I've tried including a `SET time_zone="+00:00";` before my insert, but that did not change anything. I didn't see anything in the [connection string options](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-connection-options.html), either.

I realize that I could do something like `CONVERT_TZ(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp), @@session.time_zone, '+00:00')`, but I'd rather avoid all the pointless conversion if I can, especially as the [`from_unixtime` docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime) warn that the conversion may not be lossless.

I'm using MySQLConnector/Net 6.9.6 if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem was of my own making. DateTimeOffset.Date returns a DateTime *without an offset*. Oops.

If anyone has a similarly strange problem, here are a few things that were very helpful while trying to figure out what the connector was up to:

[Enabling MySQL tracing](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-tracing-mysql.html)

Root around inside the connection object to see what it thinks the timezone is:

```cs
object driver = conn.GetType().GetField("driver", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(conn);
object tzOffset = driver.GetType().GetField("timeZoneOffset", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(driver);
```

Check the zone offset using SQL:

```cs
TimeSpan? timediff = new MySqlCommand("SELECT TIMEDIFF(NOW(), UTC_TIMESTAMP())", conn).ExecuteScalar() as TimeSpan?;
DateTime? nullable = new MySqlCommand("SELECT NOW()", conn).ExecuteScalar() as DateTime?;
```